# wifi radio link speed ios

Tags: ios

I am working on the task where I need to fetch Wi-Fi radio informations of iPhone like BSSID,SSID and link speed of the radio.

is there any API available to get the link speed of wi-fi radio iphone?

Thanks,
Jkaps

Answer (score 0):

Core Telephony framework is useful in getting such information.

I recently found a library in github which makes use core Telephony.

[https://github.com/valexa/VAFieldTest][1]